# PhoneGap and iOS 8: Failed to load local files ONLY after updating my app

Tags: ipad, cordova, ios8, local-files

I'm developing a `PhoneGap` `application` where the user is able to navigate some pages served by a server. When the user navigates to those pages, the app downloads all the files (`HTML`, `CSS`, `JS`, etc.) and store them in the `iPad`. This way, if the user tries to access those pages being `offline`, the local files are served.

This app worked fine in `iOS` 7. Yesterday I decided to update my `iPad` to `iOS` 8, and at first it seemed it worked: I can download the files, go offline and still navigate the pages using the local files. The only error I'm getting in the `Console` is:

```
[Error] Deprecated attempt to access property 'userAgent' on a non-Navigator object.
```

The problem comes when I update my app or use "phonegap local run ios" with the app installed. Whenever I do it, the app becomes unable to load the local files:

```
Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server. 
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7A3590E8-C78A-4F45-B5B9-51FD0BAFE524/Library/files/pages/7/7a56ab3cfa56fbd1b9c4becbf5dca4a2.jpg
```

The files are there, I can read them using the `File` plugin, but the WebView is unable to load them. I'm referencing them like this:

```
<img src="file://localhost/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7A3590E8-C78A-4F45-B5B9-51FD0BAFE524/Library/files/pages/7/7a56ab3cfa56fbd1b9c4becbf5dca4a2.jpg" >
```

I tried to use both `Library` and `Compatibility` as `iosPersistentFileLocation`, but the result is the same. I'm marking all the downloaded files as "don't backup" to prevent them being included in `iCloud`:

```
fileEntry.setMetadata(function(){}, function(){}, {"com.apple.MobileBackup": 1});
```

At first I thought this was caused by the known bug to load local files in `iOS` 8, but my app IS loading them, it just stops working after I update the app.

I have `PhoneGap` and all the `plugins` updated to the last version. I also tried using `Cordova` and the same happens.

Anybody knows how can I solve this or where should I report this bug?

Thank you!

Comment: If you haven't seen it yet this is a known issue: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/why-ios-8-could-break-your-hybrid-mobile-app/

Comment: I had read that issue, and I think that PhoneGap is using the old WebView because of this. My app is able to load local files, the problem comes when I update the app, then it becomes unable to load them until they are downloaded again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve it! I was using fileEntry.toURL to get the file URLs to use in my HTML. If I use

```
fileEntry.toInternalURL()
```

instead, it works fine.

With internal URL the URLs are like this:

```
cdvfile://localhost/persistent/pages/7/0b0cc746c5e90ee7fc94b2c15d37d43e.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and I managed to solve it. In my case, my problem was that every time I update the app, the new app has a different id than the last one. For instance, the path for the older app was:

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7A3590E8-C78A-4F45-B5B9-51FD0BAFE524/Library/files/file.pdf
```

And new one:

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1BC5FS-7B3B-90E8-C7C8-1B7C1984C2A71/Library/files/file.pdf
```

So even though my pdf files were still on the application data storage, I was using the wrong path since the app created a new application id. I solved this by creating a new function that updates my path every time there is an update. I find the application id by using:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);

function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    //Do what you need here
  }
```

The filesystem is an object contains the nativeURL inside the root.

Hope it helps!